# Is the sensitivity and specifity a single number for a binary classification?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I developed a binary Machine Learning model to distinguish 2 cases.  Hot and Cold.  When I carry out the python commands:

```
FP = cm.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(cm)
FN = cm.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(cm)
TP = np.diag(cm)
TN = cm.sum() - (FP + FN + TP)

FP = FP.astype(float)
FN = FN.astype(float)
TP = TP.astype(float)
TN = TN.astype(float)

# Sensitivity, hit rate, recall, or true positive rate
TPR = TP/(TP+FN)
```

I get an answer for the TRP as [0.9875 0.9541]

Here is the code for the CM:

```
y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
y_true = np.argmax(y_inference, axis=-1)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

How do I state the value for the sensitivity of the model?

Comment: The equations you post do not hold for binary classification; `TP` should be a single number, and not `np.diag(cm)`. Please post your confusion matrix.

Comment: @desertnaut, I have added the code and also the output for the CM.

Comment: Which of the two classes is the positive one?

Comment: @desertnaut, Hot is the positive class as the top left most block is the TP. the `TP` gets returned an array also `[39, 56]`.

Comment: So, the lower right block is your TN, the upper right is your FN, and the lower left is your FP; do you have your answer now?

Comment: I think I have already clarified that `TP = np.diag(cm)` is *not* correct here; your TP is simply 39. Please revisit the notion of confusion matrix for binary classification (you have probably found these equations from an answer of mine here at SO for *multi-class* classification).